# Nuget dependencies resolution using referenced projects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

We have a solution from where we build nuget packages. In addition there is a web application within the same solution that uses project references to include code from these packages. The version number (in AssemblyInfo.cs) is 11.0.0.0. Then we have another solution that uses the nuget packages from the first one. From this second solution we also build nuget packages, where we specify at least version 11.0.0.0 of the nugets from the first solution (in the nuspec-file). And to complicate matters the web application uses these second nuget packages.

Then we arrive at the problem. The nuget packages from the second solution tries to install nuget packages from the first solution when installed for the web application, even if these are added as project references. it seems like the nuget dependency resolution only looks at packages.config, and disregards the referenced DLLs.

Any ideas on how to fix it, so that the nuget installation for the web application doesn't try to install the references projects as nugets?

Our environment: ASP.Net MVC using .Net Framework 4.8. Visual Studio 2019.

Regards,
Bjørn Terje Svennes

Comment: Why can't you go with nugets all the way down? I mean don't directly reference dll in Web app, but install them as nugets. Alternatively, you can install with option to ignore dependencies, so in that case only nuget from second solution will be intalled.

Comment: Because we use the web application as a debugging platform for the nuget packages. Ignoring dependencies is an option, but one I hope to avoid.